# How to rename a column in a table with Flask + SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I created two tables for my truck scheduling application:

```
class appts_db(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    carrier = db.Column(db.String(100))
    material = db.Column(db.String(10))
    pickup_date = db.Column(db.String(10))

class carriers_db(db.Model):
    carrier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    carrier = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(15))
```

How can I rename the column *carrier* to *carrier_name* in both tables to make it more clear what the columns contain. I tried using the command prompt

```
>python3
>db.create_all()
```

But the column name doesn't update. Is there some command that I'm missing that can update the column name in the db?

Answer (score 0):

(1.) This seems to be a question about "how to migrate a single table?", twice. That is, whatever answer works for `appts_db` will also need to be applied to `carriers_db` -- I don't see a FK relation so I think most technical solutions would need to be manually told about that 2nd rename.

(2.) There are many nice "version my schema!" approaches, including the usual ruby-on-rails approach. Here, I recommend [alembic](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/). It takes some getting used to, but once implemented it lets you roll forward / roll back in time, and table schemas will match the currently-checked-out source code's expectations. It is specifically very good at column renames.

(3.) The simplest possible thing you could do here is a pair of DROP TABLE and then re-run the `db.create_all()`. The existing table is preventing create_all from having any effect, but after the DROP it will do just what you want. Of course, if you care about the existing rows you will want to tuck them away somewhere before you get too adventurous.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [*DB Browser for SQLite*](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) (I had downloaded it previously) and ran this code in the "Execute SQL" tab:

```
ALTER TABLE carriers_db
RENAME COLUMN carrier TO carrier_name;
```